# Easy way to change Grid.Row and Grid.Column in many controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, grid

I have this situation 1000 times already:
I have grid with 2 columns and many rows. Mostly i have TextBlock in first column and TextBox in second but not always. Now when I have 50 rows and I decide to move row 49 to the first row in grid, and I don't want to swap rows, I want to insert it to first place. Then I need to change values of Grid.Row and Grid.Column of all the rest of controls. This i driving me crazy. How can I make this easier?

Comment: Is this a runtime behavior or do you mean something you do at dev time in XAML?

Comment: Why you just not swap values of Grid.Row="0" Grid.Row="49" ?

Comment: `UniformGrid` or use Designer

Answer (score 0):

If you have formatted your xaml code well, you can hold **Alt** key to select and cut Grid.Row="x" in every line and hold **Alt** key to select and paste them one line down.

eg.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="a"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="b"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="c"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="d"/>
```

you want to move `<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="d"/>` to the top. Just hold "**Alt**" key to select and copy:

```
Grid.Row="1"
Grid.Row="2"
Grid.Row="3"
```

Use **Alt** key again to paste them to replace the original

```
Grid.Row="0"
Grid.Row="1"
Grid.Row="2"
```

so you well get

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="a"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="b"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="c"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="e"/>
```

Then just move `<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="d"/>` to the top and change it `Grid.Row` to 0

Comment: A bit too dependent on formatting, also depends on how you sort things, e.g. by row or by column.

Comment: @H.B. agree, if as OP said `I have this situation 1000 times already` I think it is the time to adapt an easy to modified formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the markup extension i outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447777/quick-and-basic-xaml-question) right from the beginning, if you then need to insert a new row that should be less trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd be better off using a [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) or [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx).

Comment: Actually it should probably be an `ItemsControl`, as there is apparently no need for selection.

Comment: @H.B. Yes you're right but I'm struggling to find a simple example to link.